# Optional route data with default value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have this routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{p1?}/{p2?}");
            });
```

The last two items are optional and actually they don't exist in most of pages and is for a specific page (That also I want it to be the landing page) however its not letting to define values for optional parameters.

I tried `{p1?=somevalue}` and I got an error telling me that `?` must be the last character. `{p1=somevalue?}` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try create two routes

1º

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute(
     name: "default",
     template: "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

2º

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "custonRoute",
    template: "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{p1?}/{p2?}");
});
```

Comment: https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-routing-in-mvc/

Comment: Yes. that it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{p1}/{p2}",
    defaults: new
    {
        culture = "en-US",
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        p1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        p2 = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Then your method signature would be something like this to set defaults:

```
public ActionResult Index(var p1 = defaultValue, var p2 = defaultValue)
```

As far as I know, you wouldn't be able to set defaults site wide, only for each action they apply to.

Whereas you look like you're trying to use the `RouteAttribute` which works the way you have attempted:

```
[HttpGet("{p1:var?}{p2:var?}"]
public ActionResult Index(var p1 = defaultValue, var p2 = defaultValue)
```

***Please note:*** I've used `var` as I don't know what your method signatures are and `defaultValue` because I don't know your defaults.

Comment: Its MVC 6, and except for p1 and p2 the routing is the default one that project itself created. its the same thing different look only. I want to know can optioanl routes have default values?

Comment: its nice using it as parameter +1

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Ah apologies, I just assumed.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani there is no MVC 6 but MVC core, Also if you want more accurate answer you need to use the Tag or explain in the question at least.